# junit and hamcrest declaration

Tags: maven, junit, hamcrest

I am using junit at 4.10 and declared hamcrest-core at 1.3 and hamcrest-library at 1.3. My question is are hamcrest-library and hamcrest-core embedded in junit 4.10. what about junit 4.11?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you browse to [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) you can search for artifacts and see their dependencies. If you are using Eclipse wit the Maven plugin, you can also click *Dependency Hierarchy* in the POM editor.

Looking on the [Maven website](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.11%7Cjar) you can see that JUnit 4.11 depends on Hamcrest 1.3:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Hamcrest library you have to add yourself.

Comment: Do I need to add hamcrest-core 1.3 dependency explicitly when I use junit 4.11?? When I googled it it said that "JUnit 4.11 no longer includes the org.hamcrest classes." both statements are contradicting.

Comment: Having hamcrest as a dependency and including hamcrest classes are 2 distinct things. "including classes" means that the classes are in the junit.jar. "as a dependency" means that you need the hamcrest jar to build/run junit. (if you are using maven: dependency will auto-magically included in your classpath. If you are not using maven you have to add the dependency manually in your classpath)

Comment: @ben75 is right. They mean there are no more Hamcrest classes *in* the jar. However it depends on them being in another jar, which it depends on.

Comment: With JUnit 4.11, when I remove the dependency for `hamcrest-all` from my `pom.xml`, I get compile errors in my tests. I assume `hamcrest-core` contains only the basic classes required to interact with Hamcrest including `Matcher`, `MatcherAssert` and `AssertionError`. You'll need the other JARs to get usable matchers.

Comment: @Alex I'd expect the scope to be 'test', is this not the case?

Comment: Yes sorry, should be test

Answer (score 6):

JUnit 4.10 & JUnit 4.11 (as depicted below):

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

... ship with the hamcrest-core 1.1 and 1.3 respectively. You can see this for yourself by leveraging the dependency plugin's tree goal (running *mvn dependency:tree*):

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testng 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ testng ---
[INFO] testng:testng:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.483s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 29 12:07:22 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As silly as this sounds, you need to include the appropriate hamcrest-library artefact to take advantage of the Hamcrest Matchers.  Hopefully this helps...