# NoSuchMethodError with Hamcrest 1.3 & JUnit 4.11

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, hamcrest

Another instance of the `NoSuchMethodError` for the JUnit & Hamcrest combination.
Offending code:

```
assertThat(dirReader.document(0).getFields(), hasItem(
    new FeatureMatcher<IndexableField, String>(equalTo("Patisnummer"), "Field key", "Field key") {
        @Override
        protected String featureValueOf(IndexableField actual) {
            return actual.name();
        } } ));
```

Commented lines 152–157 in [IndexerTest.java](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/blob/aida-9_linkXmlMetaDataAndAddFields/Search/Indexer/src/test/java/indexer/IndexerTest.java) (commit [ac72ce](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/commit/ac72ce1b73db8e48fa721bdce7d93a8ee36871bd))

Causes a NoSuchMethodError (see http://db.tt/qkkkTE78 for complete output):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
at org.hamcrest.FeatureMatcher.matchesSafely(FeatureMatcher.java:43)
at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:55)
at org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.matchesSafely(IsCollectionContaining.java:25)
at org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.matchesSafely(IsCollectionContaining.java:14)
at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:770)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:736)
at indexer.IndexerTest.testIndexContainsField(IndexerTest.java:152)
```

### The setup:

- JUnit 4.11
- Hamcrest 1.3
- Using Maven's surefire plugin (version 2.14), which uses its JUnitCoreProvider
- Java 7 (OpenJDK)
- See [pom](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/blob/aida-9_linkXmlMetaDataAndAddFields/Search/Indexer/pom.xml) (commit [ac72ce](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/commit/ac72ce1b73db8e48fa721bdce7d93a8ee36871bd))

### Background:

A [`NoSuchMethodError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) is caused by (compiled) classes that call non existing methods.  The specific case of `describeMismatch` and the JUnit + Hamcrest combination is often caused by an incompatibility between Hamcrest classes included in JUnit and versions of those classes in the Hamcrest library.

### Attempts to solve the NoSuchMethodError:

- The pom contains an explicit dependency on Hamcrest-library 1.3, Hamcrest-core 1.3, and JUnit 4.11, (in that order) as suggested by [Garrett Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554988/garrett-hall) in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878281/814206) to [Getting "NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch" when running test in IntelliJ 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869711/getting-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch-when-running)
- According to the JUnit documentation the JUnit 4.11 Maven dependency does no longer include compiled Hamcrest classes, instead it has a dependency on Hamcrest-core 1.3; so the `NoSuchMethodError` should not occur.
- Checking the dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree` as suggested by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545137/dan) in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709116/814206) to [junit and hamcrest declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660807/junit-and-hamcrest-declaration) shows the explicit dependencies on Hamcrest 1.3 and JUnit 4.11 and no other dependencies to those files (see http://db.tt/C2OfTDJB for the complete output).
- In another test the `NoSuchMethodError` was avoided by using:

  ```
  assertThat(
      "Zylab detector not available",
      d.getDetectors(),
      hasItem(Matchers.<Detector>instanceOf(ZylabMetadataXmlDetector.class)));
  ```

  In lines 120–123 of [IndexerTest.java](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/blob/aida-9_linkXmlMetaDataAndAddFields/Search/Indexer/src/test/java/indexer/IndexerTest.java) (commit [ac72ce](https://github.com/kaspervandenberg/aida/commit/ac72ce1b73db8e48fa721bdce7d93a8ee36871bd))
  instead of the more obvious:

  ```
  assertThat(
      "Zylab detector not available",
      d.getDetectors(),
      hasItem(isA(ZylabMetadataDetector.class));
  ```

  I'm uncertain whether the explicit type parameter `<Detector>`, using `instanceOf` instead of `isA`, the explicit reference to Hamcrest's `Matchers`, or a combination of those avoided the `NoSuchMethodException`; after fiddling around and trying different things it worked.
- Using explicit type parameters did not solve/avoid the error.
- Using a class derived from `BaseMatcher` instead of `FeatureMatcher` did not solve/avoid the error.

### Ideas how fix the `NoSuchMethodError`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This blog helped fix the same problem for me:

https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/mixing-junit-hamcrest-and-mockito-explaining-nosuchmethoderror/

Inside the dependencies for Mockito and Junit, the author added excludes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exclusions didn't help me, but the order of lib's helped: hamcrest dependency(library) should be before in Junit and/or Mockito dependencies

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869711/getting-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch-when-running seems can help

Comment: Note! You cannot use mockito-all since that has hamcrest (1.1) inside it, NOT as a dependcy. Instead, use mockito-core with teh hamcrest-core exclusion. You don't need to exclude hamcrest from junit 4.11 since that depends on hamcrest 1.3, only on earlier junit version.

Comment: This worked for me. Mockito-all does appear to be the offending package. It helps to run "mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=test" to root out all inherited dependencies to mockito-all - if you are working on a large project, some imported modules may be using it without your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of those other JARs has older versions of Hamcrest's `Matcher` or `BaseMatcher`. Here's a [list of JARs](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/hamcrest/BaseMatcher.html) which include the latter, though I have no idea how comprehensive that site is. Is there a Maven plugin which will show you all the dependencies that include a class similar to the dependency tree?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not (yet) aware of such a plugin, but your answer inspired an idea to combine Maven's dependency plugin, jar, and grep.  And search for BaseMatcher in the classpath.  A good startingpoint for monday.

Answer (score 2):

Using [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285873/david-harkness) tip and [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash) resulted in the following bash script:

```
( IFS=":"; for i in `mvn dependency:build-classpath | grep -v '\[INFO\]'`; do jar tf $i | awk "{print \"$i\\t\" \$1}"; done | grep Matcher )
```

(online at http://www.kaspervandenberg.net/2013/scripts/findDependencyClass.sh)

Which found that dependency `JGlobus-Core-2.0.4` has its own versions of `org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher`, `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers`, and `org.hamcrest.Matcher`.

Comment: FYI - You'll need to add a closing parenthesis to the very end of that Bash command

Comment: @HairOfTheDog added closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse, the "Open Type" tool (CTRL+SHIFT+T) can help you find the problematic package. Just search for the class name (e.g., Description), multiple occurrences of the same class from different JARs are red flags.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to reorder dependencies.
Instead of going mockito, junit,
I had to put junit, mockito.

Mockito 1.9.5 uses hamcrest 1.1 which is incompatible and causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

For a project with `Gradle` as a build tool:

```
testCompile("junit:junit:4.11") {
     exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
     exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-library' 
}
testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse:
For me, in eclipse-> project properties->Java build Path
moving mockito-all-1.9.5.jar to the bottom of the 'Order and Export' list did the trick. Just above that I have junit-4.11.jar and above that hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

I solved this `jar hell` problem in my `Gradle` project with the code below:

```
    testCompile (group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4+') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testCompile ('org.mockito:mockito-core:1+') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
```